# 302 Redirect all pages to homepage - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect, response.redirect, http-status-code-302

Is there a way using ASP.NET that I can 302 (temporary) redirect all pages on the website to the homepage (obviously not redirecting the homepage)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in your *Global.asax* file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.LocalPath != "/Home.aspx")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

From the [HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) article:

> ASP.NET performs the redirection by returning a 302 HTTP status code.